# How to display the division when open the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I want to see (display as block) #link1 when the page opens. Is there a way to do this with css and html? or if there is not, how can I do this with javascript?

```css
.tab div {
  display: none;
}

.tab div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>

  <div id="link1">
    <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="link2">
    <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
    <h4>Great success!</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="link3">
    <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What about `#link1 { display:block; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tab div {
  display: none;
}

.tab div[opened] {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">

<a href="#link1">Link 1</a>   
<a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#link3">Link 3</a>

<div id="link1" opened>
  <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>

<div id="link2">
  <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
  <h4>Great success!</h4>
</div>

<div id="link3">
  <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
  <p>Yeah!</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Add Event Listener on three links and add attribute opened to proper div. Or, you could use bootstrap or Material-ui collapse feature if you can use any css framework.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to trigger a click on the first `.tab a`.

Another would be set the url hash to `#link1`

```js
document.querySelector('.tab a').click()
// OR
location.hash = 'link1';
```

```css
.tab div {
  display: none;
}

.tab div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>

  <div id="link1">
    <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="link2">
    <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
    <h4>Great success!</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="link3">
    <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```